# How can I export an animation to be viewed in 3D

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I'm working on an animation in blender and I want it to be viewed in 3D on a television using a SamsungSSG-5150GB 3D-Active Glass. How can I export the animation in 3D.

Answer (score 5):

1. In the *Properties Panel > Scene Context > Views Tab* activate **Views** and **Stereo 3D**
   [image: Stereo 3D in Blender scene]
2. Select your camera and in the *Properties Panel > Camera Context > Stereoscopy Tab* select **Off-Axis**. Set **Convergence Plane Distance** to the distance the viewer is seated from the Television. Set **Interocular Distance** to the space between the viewers pupils, usually 7 - 10 cm.
   [image: Stereo Camera Settings]
3. Go to the *Properties Tab* of the *3D Viewport* and find the *Stereoscopy* section. Select 3D, and check **Cameras**, **Plane** and **Volume** to see the layout of the 3D camera in the viewport.
   [image]
4. Make sure your animated and still objects are behind the (Convergence) Plane in general. If they're supposed to come in front of the TV, they have to come in front of the convergence plane. This effect does rarely work well on most television sets and should be avoided. You may need to adjust the scaling of your scene. Since the Interocular Distance is set in centimetres in the Viewport, the 3D props should have the correct scale.
   [image]
5. Render your scene. Two image sequences will be created. One with the left camera suffix "_L" and one with the right camera suffix "_R". To separate them, so Blender can read them easier, open up the directory with the sequences. Filter search by "_L". Select the left image sequence files and move them to another directory.

To join both sequences into one movie, there can be many layouts, I will describe the [side by side layout](http://static.gigapan.org/gigapans0/158254/images/158254-900x250.jpg).

6. Set the scenes width to twice the width of your image sequences.
   [image: Double Scene Size]
7. Open the Video Sequence Editor and add the left image sequence. In the VSE, check **Image Offset** under *Strip Input*.
8. Add the right image sequence above the left strip. Check **Image Offset** under *Strip Input* and set the **X** values to the width of your images. Set the **Blend** mode to *Alpha Over*.
   [image: Sequences aligned]
   [image: Right Image Settings]
9. You will have both sequences side by side next to each other. Render as a movie format accepted by your television.
10. Playback the movie file on your television set. Press the *3D* button on your remote and cycle through the modes untill you reach 3D side by side with both images next to each other. The television will then adjust the image automatically.